# Why is jGit's RevWalk.reset() method misbehaving?

Tags: java, git, version-control, jgit

Let's say we have two files in a git repository, path/to/file1.txt and path/to/file2.txt. file1.txt was committed first, then file2.txt, so they belong to commits with different SHA1s. I'd like to retrieve the SHA1 that corresponds to each file using jGit. Here's the code I have so far:

```java
String localPath = "/path/to/repo";
Repository localRepo = new FileRepository(localPath + "/.git");

Ref headRef = localRepo.getRef("refs/heads/master");
RevWalk revWalk = new RevWalk(localRepo);
RevCommit headCommit = revWalk.parseCommit(headRef.getObjectId());
TreeWalk tw = new TreeWalk(localRepo);
tw.addTree(headCommit.getTree());
tw.setRecursive(true);

HashMap<String, String> fileShas = new HashMap<String, String>();
RevWalk commitFinder = new RevWalk(localRepo);

while (tw.next()) {
  ArrayList<PathFilter> filters = new ArrayList<PathFilter>();
  filters.add(PathFilter.create(tw.getPathString()));

  commitFinder.reset();
  RevCommit iterHead = commitFinder.lookupCommit(headRef.getObjectId());
  commitFinder.markStart(iterHead);
  commitFinder.setTreeFilter(AndTreeFilter.create(PathFilterGroup.create(filters), TreeFilter.ANY_DIFF));
  commitFinder.setRevFilter(MaxCountRevFilter.create(1));

  RevCommit commit = commitFinder.next();
  fileShas.put(tw.getPathString(), commit.getId().getName());
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. I get the correct SHA1 for the first file, but not the second one. It looks like `commitFinder.reset();` isn't doing its job. If I create a new `RevWalk` on each iteration, it works but is extremely slow. Any ideas why `reset()` isn't working?

Answer (score 0):

Though this doesn't answer the question I put my findings here for better readability. The `getLatestModification` method from the test shown below returns the id of the commit in which the given file was last modified.

Though the code is shorter than the original snippet, the problem remains that `reset` apparently doesn't work.

```
public class RevWalkResetLearningTest {

  @Rule
  public final TemporaryFolder tempFolder = new TemporaryFolder();

  private Repository repository;

  @Test
  public void testReset() throws Exception {
    RevWalk revWalk = new RevWalk( repository );
    RevCommit beerCommit = getLastModification( revWalk, "plugins/emoji/public/images/beer.png" );
//    RevCommit discourseCommit = getLastModification( new RevWalk( repository ), "images/discourse.png" );
    RevCommit discourseCommit = getLastModification( revWalk, "images/discourse.png" );

    assertEquals( "8278fdb9ddbc61eea9f6e6045b705106678ce532", beerCommit.name() );
    assertEquals( "50cd44df2dec27c0834be4a2975fe175c3fac64f", discourseCommit.name() );
  }

  private RevCommit getLastModification( RevWalk revWalk, String path ) throws IOException {
    revWalk.reset();
    revWalk.markStart( revWalk.parseCommit( repository.resolve( "refs/heads/master" ) ) );
    revWalk.setTreeFilter( AndTreeFilter.create( PathFilter.create( path ), TreeFilter.ANY_DIFF ) );
    return revWalk.next();
  }

  @Before
  public void setUp() throws Exception {
//    Git git = Git.cloneRepository().setURI( "https://github.com/discourse/discourse.git" ).setDirectory( tempFolder.getRoot() ).call();
//    repository = git.getRepository();
    repository = new FileRepositoryBuilder().setMustExist( true ).setGitDir( new File( "/path/to/discourse/.git" ) ).build();
  }

  @After
  public void tearDown() {
    repository.close();
  }
}
```

The test fails because the commit-id of `discourseCommit` is the same as `beerCommit`. If I change the code so that each call to `getLastModification` gets a new instance of `RevWalk` (see the commented line), the test succeeds.

I suggest to open a [bug report](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=JGit&rep_platform=All&op_sys=All) or ask the JGit [mailing list](https://dev.eclipse.org/mailman/listinfo/jgit-dev) for help.

Comment: Great example, thank you! I think your test's commit history might be a bit too simple to surface the issue, however. I'm trying to get the commit in which each file was last **modified**. I have tried this mostly with the source code from the [Discourse project](https://github.com/discourse/discourse). Here's an example from discourse. The technique described in this question says `plugins/emoji/public/images/beer.png` was last modified in `189b1c72`, but `git log plugins/emoji/public/images/beer.png` says it was only changed in `8278fdb9`.

Comment: Moreover, `git show --name-only 189b1c72` does **not** list `plugins/emoji/public/images/beer.png` as having changed in the commit. The commit message ("FEATURE: query param for topic state") doesn't appear to have anything to do with emoji.

Comment: I'm using jgit 3.4.1.201406201815-r.

Comment: The `beer.png` is a symbolic link. For a long time those were [not supported by JGit](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=354367). In Feb 2014 support for symbolic link was [merged](https://git.eclipse.org/r/#/c/9379/) - but I'm not sure in which release version it is available, if any. May that be (part of) the problem?

Comment: I've updated the test to use the discourse repository and there I can reproduce that `reset` apparently doesn't work.

Comment: Great, thanks. I've filed a bug with jGit: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=439856